# Converting String to Integer JOptionPane

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, integer

Am trying to get an input from user as an integer (age). But I keep getting "String cannot be converted to string" and "bad operand types for binary operator '<='and '>='. Any help will be much appreciated

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class LotionFinder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String response;
        response = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please Enter Your Age:"));
        if (response == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Contact a Sales Representative For a Private Consultation");
        } else if (response.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Contact a Sales Representative For a Private Consultation");
        } else if (response <= 3 && response >= 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's Recommended That You Purchase Our No-Tears Baby Lotion!");
            
        }
        

        System.exit (0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `String response` to `Integer response`

Comment: Thank you so much took me 2 hours to figure this out lol

Comment: Your program won't work if the user does not enter any value though.

Comment: Hmmm okay nvm, how do I work around that?

Comment: It is always good to add the error's stacktrace on your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest first getting the value from JOptionPane as a `String`

```
String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please Enter Your Age:");
```

Then checking if the user has entered something then  parse it to `Integer`

```
     if (response.length() !=0) {
    responseToInt = Integer.parseInt(response);
```

With try and catch, we can limit that the user should enter only numbers.

```
            try {
                responseToInt = Integer.parseInt(response);
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
                 response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please Enter Your Age:");
            }
```

FULL CODE

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer responseToInt = 0;
       String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please Enter Your Age:");
        if (response.length() !=0) {
            try {
                responseToInt = Integer.parseInt(response);
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
                 response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please Enter Your Age:");
            }
        }  if (responseToInt <= 3 && responseToInt >= 1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It's Recommended That You Purchase Our No-Tears Baby Lotion!");

        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Contact a Sales Representative For a Private Consultation");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever user enters a value the program just ends. I'm guessing coz 'responseToInt' is assigned the value 0? I'm very new to Java so please bear with me @Typhon

Comment: Try to enter 2. and you will see that is not because it is not assigned with 0

Comment: It will respond only if the number is <=3 and >=1 like you have mentioned

Comment: Yes, but when I enter numbers 1 - 3 the program just ends. And I'm just guessing coz the variable 'responseToInt' is declared and assigned the value of 0 so the program just ends 0 isn't apart of the condition for the baby lotion?

Comment: 0 its just for starting point the Integer is assigned with a new value after taking input from user

Comment: ok thanks it worked lol... I just edited the else if to the second if it works now thanks. So if I add the 
`if (responseToInt == null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Contact a Sales Representative For a Private Consultation");`
for when I click cancel it should show the default message right?